# Takfir of people you don't know

Tags: kufr, takfir

Assalamu alaikum!!! My sister is sometimes very much interested in Muslim celebrities. However, some of them celebrate Christmas, Halloween, make jokes about religion and more. Should they be given takfir in this situation or not? And will I become a kafir myself if I don't?

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, passing Takfir is a serious matter that **requires deep knowledge** and understanding of Islamic jurisprudence. It is not appropriate for individuals to make such **judgments**, especially regarding public figures like celebrities!

While it is essential for Muslims to uphold their faith and values, it is NOT within our authority to declare Takfir label on others based on their actions.

**It is better to get help from your local religious advisor.**

Answer (score 0):

**This is a matter of serious significance in Islam and is taken very seriously. The case of takfir is based on vast knowledge in the principles of Islamic laws and is to be dealt with very cautiously**